# Thread taking long time. Why?

Tags: android

I'm creating app to check for duplicate files in my sd cards.
I get whole file list in the "files" `ArrayList`.
Now I need to find duplicate files,so i used this code in the thread.
But it's working but it takes too much time to find duplicate.

```
for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++)
    {
      for(int j=i+1;j<files.size();j++)
        {
        if(new File(files.get(i)).getName().compareTo(new File(files.get(j)).getName())==0)
        {
            //My Code
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's O(N^2) and you are allocating N^2 times the same object, so no wonder it's slow.

Comment: Use a HashSet to check duplicates.

Comment: Also, it's possible Android is actually accessing the file system, which would make everything much slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider adding all elements to a `HashSet` and adding them back to the `ArrayList`. Something like

```
Set<File> set = new HashSet<File>();
set.addAll(files);
files.clear();
files.addAll(set);
```

Now if you compare the size of `set` and `files`, you know if you had duplicates or not

**EDIT** 
Changed `HashSet` to `Set<File>` as suggested

Comment: It is good practice to use generics and interfaces: `Set<File> set = new HashSet<File>();`

Comment: Assuming you have the memory on the phone to use a hashset, this is the best solution. Otherwise, use an nlog(n) sorting algorithm and then do a linear scan to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, creating a thread is quite expensive, checkout [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

If you create same threads often - AsyncTask might be a good choice, because it will manage thread creation/stop for you in a good way.

Here are some tweaks for presented code:

- cache `files.size()` once, store it in a variable and use it;
- `new File(files.get(i)).getName()` is not needed to be called for every j, can be cached;
- Try to avoid `new` calls inside loops. I'm not sure on why do You need to call `new File()` at all instead of just comparing `files.get()` result;